# How to make price range system in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a price range system using `php/mysql` for a `product table`

**exemple this is the table**

Here is **product table:**

```
id name       price 
1  pen          25
2  pencil       75
3  rubber       100
4  bag         250
5  bike        800
```

This is what i want to achieve

```
if we select price 

from 0 - 30 (1) Only product of that range should display 

if we select price 
from 100 - 250 (1) Only product of that range should display 

and so on...
```

How can i achieve that with php and mysql? 
Any tips,guidance will be helpful. 
How should i undertake this task for a php newbie.

Comment: You should learn about basic MySQL queries first... anyways, it could look like this: `SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE price > 0 AND price < 30`

Comment: @Tanuel Mategi: yesss..Thanks..I see

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL `between` :-

```
select * from product where price between 0 and 30
```

or

```
select * from product where price between 100 and 250
```

Comment: I should use BETWEEN for each option like this: for product price from          0-30  SELECT *
FROM product table
WHERE price 
BETWEEN
0 AND 30;                                                                                                              for price between 50-100                                                                                        SELECT *
FROM product table
WHERE price 
BETWEEN
50 AND 100; and so on...right?

Comment: thanks..seem to be easy...i will try and be back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)**

```
SELECT *
FROM product table
WHERE price 
BETWEEN
0 AND 30;// pass your range here
```

Comment: I should use BETWEEN for each option like this: for product price from          0-30  SELECT *
FROM product table
WHERE price 
BETWEEN
0 AND 30;                                                                                                              for price between 50-100                                                                                        SELECT *
FROM product table
WHERE price 
BETWEEN
50 AND 100; and so on...right?

Comment: :thanks..seem to be easy...i will try and be back to you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Between keyword of Mysql. Between keyword checks a value in between a range. 
Use this query. Change values according to your need.

Suppose your lower limit is `$price1` and higher limit is `price2`

```
Select * from product where price between $price1 and $price2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am explain that how price ranger will work in select query

query will be like that

```
Select * from product where price between $lower and $higher;
```

> `$lower` is min value of price ranger and
>
> `$higher` is higher value  of price ranger